# Question about rigid body and constraints

Tags: constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I have created an animation with the Rigid Body. It is a simulation of a robotic arm. It is a 3D printable arm that I arranged in Blender.
It works well for the constraints that have all the same direction (the arm itself).

But I am not able to add a constraint for the rotation. The rotation direction of the "normal arm" constraints is in the X direction, and the bottom plate is supposed to rotate about the Z direction.

I need a way to link the X-direction constraints to the Z-rotation. I can animate the two servo driven arms and the arm moves correctly, but I can't use the rotation, the arms don't rotate and the thing gets broken.

[image: Screenshot of robotarm with empties (constraints)]

Any hints?

[image]

Comment: To be honest I'd just use normal rigging methods for a simple arm like that, maybe with an IK constraint, rather than Rigid body which I've never used. There are lots of YT tutorials on rigging robot arms online and a very detailed one on rigging an aircraft landing gear [here](https://youtu.be/tV2MhgnnvOg).

Comment: I know the Inverse-Kinematic-thing when animating people and so, but am not sure if it is capable of animation of such a mechanical arm.
I don't need an animation to move the "hand", i need an animation that follows the rotations of the two arms that are driven by servos in the printed version.

Comment: may i ask why you want to use rigid body here? because as far as i could see you animate it anyway..."normally" you would let Blender do the physics and e.g. just animate a motor constraint to move parts....

Comment: und mein Kompliment....! Ich habe noch nie ein so sophisticated rigid body robot arm gesehen....!!

Answer (score 1):

ok, i don't know whether you want it that way, but here is an example how you could do the rotation via a motor:

1. delete all keyframes and uncheck the animated checkboxes of all animated rigid bodies
2. Add a motor constraint like this:

[image]
[image]

then you can animate the target velocity (what i did)

3. add another motor constraint here:

[image]

[image]

result:

(all driven by simulation, nothing animated except the velocities of the motors)

[image]

i think i don't have to tell you that the direction of the constraint is very important - because you wouldn't have come so far if you didn't know that ;)

Viel Erfolg!!